# Why do I receive this Python Error 'Object has no attribute' when it is defined already?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've had some trouble with this small program for the past few days. It's a small introduction to classes, methods, and attributes in Python. Every time I run this program, I run into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "9_7.py", line 55, in <module>
    permit.display_priv()
  File "9_7.py", line 50, in display_priv
    for k in self.privs_one :
AttributeError: 'Admin' object has no attribute 'privs_one'
```

I don't understand why because the attribute is clearly defined in my program, but Python appears to ignore it completely. (Code below):

```
#This program will create a class and several methods for the object Users
#Two attributes will be stored first_name and last_name
#Followed by the definition of two methods called describe_user and
#greet_user. More will be explained below:

class User:
    """Definition of a class to model a User Profile."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, user_age, user_town):
       """Initialize name, age, and hometown attributes"""
       self.first = first_name
       self.last = last_name
       self.age = user_age
       self.town = user_town

    def describe_user(self):
        """
        Method provides the profile of the User including their name, age, and
        hometown.
        """
        print(f"First Name: {self.first}")
        print(f"Last Name: {self.last}")
        print(f"Age:       {self.age}")
        print(f"Hometown:  {self.town}")

    def greet_user(self):
        """Creates a personalized statement greeting the user."""
        print(f"Welcome {self.first} {self.last}, glad to see you back!")


#Creates a new class called Admin to indicate the administrative user
#Will display administrator privledges through the method show_privledges

class Admin(User):
    """Definition of the class Admin"""
    """Admin will inherit the properties of the parent class Admin"""

    def __init___(self, first_name, last_name, user_age, user_town): 
        """
        Initialize the attributes of the parent class
        Creates an attribute called privleges that stores a string
        that displays the permissions of the Admin User.
        """
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, user_age, user_town)
        self.privs_one = ["Can Add Post", "Can Delete Post", "Can Modify Accounts"]

    def display_priv(self):
        """Shows the permissions of the administrator"""
        print(f"Welcome {self.first} {self.last}")
        for k in self.privs_one :
            print(k)

permit = Admin('Gerald', 'Lavert', 25, 'Oregon')

permit.display_priv()
```

I wrote a functionally similar program earlier and encountered no issues, but this one confuses me placed in comparison. I would appreciate some assistance in resolving this problem.

Comment: Count the number of underscores in the name of your `__init__` method.

Comment: Thank You! A silly mistake, it worked now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Admin` class, change:

```
def __init___(self, first_name, last_name, user_age, user_town):    # There are 3 '_'.
```

To:

```
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, user_age, user_town):
```